# finding a text wirhin a struct type column in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to find the number of occurrence of a "matches_count" text in a struct type column of a dataframe. How can I accomplish this in pyspark. I need to return a column with the count. Also the structure varies for every row so that same keys might or might not be present in the row.

```
"abcviolation": {
                "2020.06.01.xls": {
                    "twnin": {
                        "matches_count": 1
                    },
                    "phtaxid": {
                        "matches_count": 30
                    },
                    "driverslicense": {
                        "matches_count": 15
                    },
                    "DICard_Term": {
                        "matches_count": 1
                    },
                    "resident": {
                        "matches_count": 30
                    },
                    "win": {
                        "matches_count": 30
                    },
                    "port2": {
                        "matches_count": 1
                    },
                    "id_2": {
                        "matches_count": 30
                    },
                    "id_3": {
                        "matches_count": 6
                    },
                    "id_4": {
                        "matches_count": 30
                    }
                }
            },
```

the output dataframe would've a column "no_of_occurrence" with the value of 10 for this row.

Comment: I've edited the question with the output.

Comment: is it a mistake in the example data that id_3 appears twice?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question

Comment: Could you please clarify what format is your input? In the question's text you say you have a struct type column, but in the sample code I see what looks like Python/Json object. What is the actual type of the column(s) in your input dataframe?

Comment: Its because the data has been formatted in a JSON format. The actual column abcviolation is of struct type so is 2020.06.01.xls and twnin while matches_count is of type long.

Comment: You mention that the structure "varies for every row". Spark struct type is fixed, it can't vary from one row to another inside one dataframe. So I'm suspecting your column either (a) String with Json, (b) Json object, (c) You don't have a dataframe yet - the data is in the file. Is any of these correct? If so - which one? If the data is still in the file - how do example lines in the file look like? If you do have dataframe, say `mydf` - what is its schema - i.e. what does pyspark output when you do `print(mydf)`?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the data is not fixed (for example if the same code should be applied to many different datasets with slightly different structure), one approach could be to transform the whole struct into a string and search for the number of occurences of `matches_count` within this string.

```python
#create a new column containing a (json) string representation of the data
df2 = df.withColumn("json", F.to_json(F.struct("abcviolation")))

#define a udf that counts the number of occurences of 'matches_count' within a string
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
def count_matches_count(str):
    return str.count('matches_count')
count_udf = F.udf(count_matches_count, LongType())

#create a new column with the help of the udf that contains the count
df3 = df2.withColumn("count", count_udf("json"))
```

The result is

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|        abcviolation|                json|count|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|[[[1], [15], [30]...|{"abcviolation":{...|   10|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

This approach has some caveats: calling `to_json` in the first step will loose data if there are duplicate keys in the json. And the count might be too high if the string `matches_count` also occurs somewhere as data field name.